# Jquery dblClick() doesnt work with dynamically added elemnets

Tags: javascript, jquery

Looking to add some functionality when users double click on a div to pop up a box. I already have the pop-up functionality which works with inline onClick(). But I would like to change this to double click.

I have tried the following which will work if invoked after an element is added.

```
$(".dz-preview").dblclick(function() {
    console.log("inside dbl");
    renameFile(this);
});
```

But I cant seem to figure out how to get it to work on dynamically generated elemenets.

Comment: This is one of many duplicates you may want to look at event delegation.

Comment: That obviously won't work because when that is executed the element doesn't exists so the event listener can't be attached, you need to use .on() so it will constantly look for the elements and that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('dblclick', '.dz-preview', function() {
    console.log("inside dbl");
    renameFile(this);
});
```

Comment: my hero. ha. I tried the on. but I had dz-preview where document should have been. Thanks so much!